# Mobile_Detect.php and Drupal

Tags: theming

How might I make use of this [Mobile Detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) php class in a D7 site? Rather new to this so I'm really not sure where this can be implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a module to do just that, [Mobile Detect](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_detect):

> This is a lightweight mobile detection based on the Mobile_Detect.php
>   library, which can be obtained from the GitHub repository.
>
> This module is intended to aid developers utilizing mobile-first and
>   responsive design techniques who also have a need for slight changes
>   for mobile and tablet users. An example would be showing (or hiding) a
>   block or content pane to a particular device.
>
> This module is not intended (and never will be enhanced) to provide
>   theme switching or redirection; other modules already provide this
>   functionality.

There is also [Context Mobile Detect](http://drupal.org/project/context_mobile_detect):

> This is a Context module which integrates Context and PHP Mobile
>   Detect library Mobile_Detect.
>
> Module preserve drupal page cache working.

And you can check out [Mobile Switch](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_switch):

> The Mobile Switch module provides a simple automatic theme switch
>   functionality for mobile devices, detected by Browscap or Mobile
>   Detect.

These all serve slightly different audiences.  Pick the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: thanks for this! Are you able to suggest any simple method of redirecting to a mobile site?

Comment: @juneuprising  Added bit about a module I just learned about.  In the past I have used Mobile Tools to handle mobile redirection (in combination with Domain Access for sharing some content), but that just uses Browscap for device detection.  You may also want to check out Adaptive Theme, which has mobile/tablet support.

Comment: I've tried Mobile Switch, but it seems to just support switching themes. Is there a way for me to simply redirect to a single page that I've created as a landing page for mobile devices?

Comment: Do a search, the may have been a question about it.  Otherwise, post a new question and explain your situation a bit more.